# Why there is no google earth 7.1.5 for Ubuntu?

Tags: google, google-earth

Got a mail from google stating that that "after May 29, 2015, OAuth 1.0 will no longer be supported and Google Earth versions 7.1.4 or earlier will not be able to authenticate to GME." But no update for Ubuntu is available and  the version 7.1.5 is only available for Windows and Mac. So how to install version 7.1.5 in Ubuntu?

**EDIT: [google earth for linux has updated finally.](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/09/google-earth-for-linux-update-finally)

Google Earth 7.1.5 can also be installed in Ubuntu using Wine**

Comment: How are we meant to answer that? Google doesn't care about linux?

Comment: No... I meant that Ask Ubuntu doesn't control Google's choice of programs... What do you expect us to say?

Comment: Probably a better question is how do you create a market for Linux ? Android seems to have a good model.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The little return (or even the complete lack of it) does not seem to be the reason for no longer supporting Linux after so many years.

I rather suspect that the NSA requested its backdoors, and it was difficult to implement in Linux.
Sad but true, we will have to find alternatives to Google.